# dispatch doesn't call reducer React Native

Tags: react-native, async-await, react-redux, use-effect, dispatch

I create a component (**AlertChild**) to show alerts using redux in React-Native.
Currently when I call the dispatch from another component(another class)and this return, then the `alertchild` shows the message ok, but when I call the dispatch from the same component (**Login**), the alert is not showed and I can verify than the reducer (**AlertReducer**) is not called because the console.log() (in class AlertReducer) shows nothing.

**AlertReducer:**

```js
export function AlertReducer(state = {}, action: any) {
  console.log("Dispatch: " + action);

  switch (action.type) {
    case "INFO":
      return {
        alert: {
          type: "info",
          message: action.message,
        },
      };
    case "DANGER":
      return {
        alert: {
          type: "danger",
          message: action.message,
        },
      };
    case "CLEAR":
      return {};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**AlertActions:**

```js
function showInfo(message: string) {
  return {
    type: "INFO",
    message,
  };
}

function showDanger(message: string) {
  return {
    type: "DANGER",
    message,
  };
}

function clear() {
  return { type: "CLEAR" };
}

export const AlertActions = {
  showInfo,
  showDanger,
  clear,
};
```

**AlertChild:**

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Toast } from "native-base";
import { AlertActions } from "../Store/Actions/AlertActions";

const AlertChild = (visible = true) => {
  const alert = useSelector((state) => state.alert.alert);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    ShowAlert();
  }, [visible, dispatch]);

  function ShowAlert() {
    if (visible && alert !== undefined && Object.keys(alert).length) {
      Toast.show({
        text: alert.message,
        buttonText: "X",
        type: alert.type,
        duration: alert.type === "danger" ? 60000 : 6000,
      });
      dispatch(AlertActions.clear());
    }
  }
  return <></>;
};

export default AlertChild;
```

**Login:**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { Text, TextInput, View, Image } from "react-native";
import { Button, Spinner } from "native-base";
import styles from "./Styles/LoginStyles";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import AlertChild from "../Components/AlertChild";
import { AlertActions } from "../Store/Actions/AlertActions";

const Login = (props: any) => {
  const { navigation } = props;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(AlertActions.clear());
  }, [dispatch]);

  async function Test() {
    dispatch(AlertActions.showInfo("Hello"));
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button onPress={async () => await Test()}>
        <Text>Test</Text>
      </Button>

      <AlertChild {...props} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

**Why the alert message is not displayed immediately?**

Comment: What is the question ?
Why the alert message is not displayed immediately? Or the reducer isn’t called at all?

Comment: @ridvanaltun both, but principal why the alert is not displayed after of dispatch?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to put in AlertChild the const "alert" (selector) in the useEffect:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    ShowAlert()
},[visible, alert, dispatch])
```